Does watching naked women count as a breach in brahmachary if so the what is the prayaschitta
As I asked before, is watching pictures of naked women considered a breach in brahmachary if so then what is the prayschitta

You should do naam japa(daily) and I have heard seeing naked women destroys punyas in Mahabharata and pray from lord I won't do this again(I'll try my best) and do naam japa as it gives power to not let it happen and listen to satsang of premanand ji maharaj
